# Updating SOME fields in nested object without overwriting others with spread operator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How to update some field in nested object without overwriting other fields in that nested object with spread operator? My function is as follows

```
exports.handler = ((data, context) => {
const profile = data.profile
const uid = context.auth.uid
const newRef = db.collection("user").doc(uid)


return newRef.update({
    profile: {...profile}
}).then(() => {
        return "Data updated seccusfully"
    })
})
```

which is suppose to update nested profile object. However the function removes also all not specified fields in that object. Is there any way to achieve update object with spread operator without removing other fields or do we have to specify each fields as the documentation says?

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
"age": 13,
"favorites.color": "Red"
})
```

My profile object contains different fields for each type of user and I'm updating the profile fileds in multiple places therefore I was hoping to simplify it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we can update some object properties without overwriting others with set method like this. Strange it doesn't work with update

```
return newRef.set({
    profile: { ...profile }
}, { merge: true }).then(() => {
    return "Data updated seccusfully"
})
```

Really appreciate all your help